# How do I write a LINQ query which will generate a JSON string with the following format?

Tags: json, linq

I have 2 related tables with schemas like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_People] (
[People_Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) ,
[ActivityDate] date NULL,
[Colour_Id] int NOT NULL
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Colours] (
[Colour_Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) ,
[Colour_Name] nvarchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL 
)
```

I am trying to arrive at a JSON string formatted like so:

```
[
    {
        "Month": "June",
        "Red": 3,
        "Blue": 1,
        "Green": 7
    },
    {
        "Month": "July",
        "Red": 6,
        "Blue": 11,
        "Green": 4
    },
    {
        "Month": "August",
        "Red": 1,
        "Blue": 5,
        "Green": 9
    }

]
```

Currently, the best I have been able to get to with LINQ is the following:

```
var query = from a in context.tbl_Colours
            join t in context.tbl_People
            on a.Colour_Id equals t.People_Id
            group a by new { a.Colour_Name, t.Colour_Id, t.ActivityDate.Value.Month } into result
            select new
            {

                Month = result.Key.Month,
                Colour = result.Key.Colour_Name,
                Frequency = result.Count()
            };

string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
```

which returns:

```
[
    {
        "Month": 6,
        "Colour": "\r\nRed\r",
        "Frequency": 1
    },
    {
        "Month": 7,
        "Colour": "\r\nGreen\r",
        "Frequency": 1
    },
    {
        "Month": 8,
        "Colour": "\r\nRed\r",
        "Frequency": 1
    }

]
```

which is appears close to what is desired but I have not been able to tweak the code to produce anything closer to what is expected. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looking at your output, it seems that the `Color_Name` values in your data have extra whitespace - that's something to fix completely outside of the code aspects.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks. I'm aware of the extra whitespace and fixing this would not be a problem. I am sure you have some ideas regarding fixing the main problem reported. Would you be kind to spare a minute or two to share them? Thanks

Comment: I don't have time right now - and we don't know whether the set of colours is fixed. You may want to use something like Json.NET and its `JObject` type in order to populate the values more dynamically.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks Jon. The set of colours are fixed. Just in case you have a sec :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your colors are fixed, you could simply do:

```
var results = (from t in context.tbl_Peoples
            join a in context.tbl_Colours
                on t.Colour_Id equals a.Colour_Id
            group a by t.ActivityDate.Value.Month
            into result
            select new
            {
                Month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(result.Key), 
                Blue = result.Count(r => r.Colour_Name.Trim() == "Blue"),
                Green = result.Count(r => r.Colour_Name.Trim() == "Green"),
                Red = result.Count(r => r.Colour_Name.Trim() == "Red"),
            });

string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
```

If your colors are not fixed and you want to build dynamic property names (e.g. Red, Green, Blue, Yellow etc.) a viable approach would be to use JSON.net objects like JArray, JObject and JProperty to generate dynamic properties and build the correct JSON output that you want.

This code should produce the JSON you expect:

```
var results = (from t in context.tbl_Peoples
                join a in context.tbl_Colours
                on t.Colour_Id equals a.Colour_Id
                group a by new { a.Colour_Name, t.Colour_Id, t.ActivityDate.Value.Month } into result
                select new
                {
                    result.Key.Month,
                    Colour = result.Key.Colour_Name.Trim(),
                    Frequency = result.Count()
                }).ToList();

var distinctMonths = results.Select(r => r.Month).Distinct().ToList();
var distinctColors = results.Select(r => r.Colour).Distinct().ToList();

var arr = new JArray();

foreach (var month in distinctMonths)
{
    var monthObject = new JObject
    {
        { "Month", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month) }
    };

    foreach (var color in distinctColors)
    {
        monthObject.Add(color, 0);
    }

    var colorsData = results.Where(d => d.Month == month).Select(a => new {a.Colour, a.Frequency});

    foreach (var color in colorsData)
    {
        monthObject[color.Colour] = color.Frequency;
    }

    arr.Add(monthObject);
}

string jsonData = arr.ToString();
```

The output JSON for some sample data would be:

```
[
  {
    "Month": "May",
    "Blue": 2,
    "Green": 1,
    "Red": 1
  },
  {
    "Month": "November",
    "Blue": 0,
    "Green": 1,
    "Red": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "January",
    "Blue": 0,
    "Green": 0,
    "Red": 2
  }
]
```

Make sure to include some error handling to handle edge cases.

Comment: ZendCoder: Thanks for your help with this: Could you please explain the line: let color = Color.FromName(result.Key.Colour_Name.Trim())? Particularly what is  intended by Color.FromName? Thanks